# Converting for loop to list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

This has been killing me!

Any idea how to convert this to a list comprehension?

```
for x in dataframe:
    if dataframe[x].value_counts().sum()<=1:
        dataframe.drop(x, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: The use of `dataframe` makes me think this might be `pandas`? Is that what you are using? What does `drop` do? Does it actually modify the list in place? If not, then where are you collecting the data that creates your new list?

Comment: It's not really appropriate for a list comprehension ... is there a reason you want it to look like that? (it's not returning any data, but modifying the object over and over again).

Answer (score 1):

`[dataframe.drop(x, axis=1, inplace=True) for x in dataframe if dataframe[x].value_counts().sum() <= 1]`

I have not used pandas yet, but the documentation on `dataframe.drop` says it returns a new object, so I assume it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably suggest going the other way and filtering it, I don't know your dataframe but something like this should work:

```
counts_valid = df.T.apply(pd.value_counts()).sum() > 1
df = df[counts_valid]
```

Or, if I see what you are doing, you may be better with

```
counts_valid = df.T.nunique() > 1
df = df[counts_valid]
```

That will just keep rows that have more than one unique value.